# Poor regular expressions in Go

Tags: regex, go

Why does the [regexp package](http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/) in Go no support decent regexp? For example the character classes \w and \s are not implemented as of Go r60.3. Also (?:non) capturing groups are not recognized.

Comment: That's interesting but is that really a question ?

Comment: The word "decent" is subjective at best, and perhaps inflammatory.  Complaining that an unfinished product is unfinished is pointless.  While r60 is the current release version, it is over six months old and development has been brisk since then.

Comment: Oh, I was definitely not complaining, just asking. I didn't know about the weekly repo either.

Comment: Not knowing the weekly wasn't the problem : that was just an error. It would have probably been better to phrase the question according to your needs. I can only guess that this would have been something like "How to do complex regexp (using \w, \s, etc) in Go ?" or "Is there a more complete regexp solution in Go than the standard package ?". The phrasing you used made it difficult to help you in a constructive way.

Comment: @dystroy Absolutely agree, I should have phrased it differently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the "current state of art" [regexp package](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/regexp/).
It has [support](http://code.google.com/p/re2/wiki/Syntax) for `\w` and `\s` and also handles non capturing groups `(?:re)`.

Comment: The question and the other two answers here are talking about the old regex package which is now in `old/regex` in the latest Go codebase and will be dropped soon. The current `regex` package is more than capable of what Q needs. Did I mention that it's fast?

Comment: "State of the art" with no look-behind/look-ahead?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT : disregard that : I hadn't had a look at the recent versions of the regexp package

If that's really a question, I suppose we could answer that nobody for now took the time to build a complete regexp library.

If you do so, don't forget to take into account that modern regexp need to be correct regarding Unicode. Speaking of the \w you mentionned, that's not so simple : 'é' is a word character. Don't port something like the standard javascript regexp packages.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states that 'Package regexp implements a simple regular expression library' so I guess it's not a priority at the moment to have a fully featured regex library.